# Iterator in java and while

Tags: java, arrays, iterator, iterable

I have to check the value in the catalog for the identifier of each person if it is less than 5 and then the note in the catalog and the person must be removed. I tried:

```
Iterator<Person> iter = persons.iterator(); 
While (iter.hasNext()) { 
    Person p = iter.next(); 
    If (p.obtineIdentificator() < 5) { 
        iter.remove(); 
    } 
}
```

And in the catalog I added them based on the identifier. Ex.:

```
catalog.put(persons.get(0).obtineIdentificator(), 5);
```

I've been trying but I don't know what to do here.

Comment: 1) `if` and `while` are Java keywords with lower-case. 2) What do you mean with *"note in the catalog"*?

Comment: `persons.removeIf(p -> p.obtineIdentificator() < 5))` would be easier, if it's a `Collection`.

Comment: I don’t understand *I don't know what to do here.*. You have written the code already. Is anything missing? Is the code doing what it’s supposed to do or not? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: There are 5 people with certain data and I put 5 notes in a catalog, and the notes are different and must be over 5 so that they are not removed.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're trying to say is that you want to remove things from `persons`, but you also want to remove the things you are removing from a map.

You can do that in three steps:

1. Get the things you're going to remove
2. Remove them from `persons`
3. Remove them from the `catalog` too

Like so:

```
// 1.
List<Person> toRemove = persons.stream().filter(p -> p.obtineIdentificator() < 5).collect(toList());

// 2.
persons.removeAll(toRemove);

// 3.
toRemove.stream().map(Person::obtineIdentificator).forEach(catalog::remove);
// or (amongst other ways)
catalog.keySet().removeAll(toRemove.stream().map(Person::obtineIdentificator).collect(toSet());
```

Comment: I have to take them out of the person and from the catalog.  Those under 5 are removed from both, and the people in person are in an ArrayList and the notes in the catalog are in the HashMap.

Comment: Then use `catalog.remove(p.obtineIdentificator())` instead of `catalog.put`.

Comment: Ok, ty so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code.

```
ListIterator<Person> iter = persons.listIterator();
while(iter.hasNext()){
    if(iter.next().getObtineIdentificator() < 5){
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```